# Solved “The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 6.0.” in an Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-6.0

I recently upgraded a project to .NET 6 and immediately started getting an error on your hosted build pipeline in Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

I made changes to my pipeline. Before the build step, I have added a “Use .NET Core”. then it started working

[image]

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. The `Core` part was removed for marketing reasons